# Multiple if condition in one function is not working

Tags: javascript, html

This is my JS code, check it out

```
function showLater1() {
    if ((vidos.currentTime >= 30) && (vidos.currentTime <= 34)) {
        lay.style.opacity = "1";
        content.style.opacity = "0";
        controls.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
        content.style.opacity = "1";
        controls.style.opacity = "1";
    }

    if ((vidos.currentTime >= 90) && (vidos.currentTime <= 94)) {

        lay.style.opacity = "1";
        content.style.opacity = "0";
        controls.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
        content.style.opacity = "1";
        controls.style.opacity = "1";
    }

    if ((vidos.currentTime >= 105) && (vidos.currentTime <= 109)) {

        lay.style.opacity = "1";
        content.style.opacity = "0";
        controls.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
        content.style.opacity = "1";
        controls.style.opacity = "1";
    }

}
```

When there was only one `if` condition, it was working well. But, when added 3 it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `currentTime` is between 105 and 109, it's always going to use the `else` blocks.

Let's assume your `currentTime` 93. It sets `content.style.opacity = "0";` from the second `if` condition. But, then the control goes to the third `else` condition.

You can just simplify it to this:

```
function showLater1() {
    if ((vidos.currentTime >= 30 && vidos.currentTime <= 34)
    || (vidos.currentTime >= 90 && vidos.currentTime <= 94)
    || (vidos.currentTime >= 105 && vidos.currentTime <= 109)) {
        lay.style.opacity = "1";
        content.style.opacity = "0";
        controls.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
        content.style.opacity = "1";
        controls.style.opacity = "1";
    }
}
```